# Need help in SED and AWK

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file "list" as following:

```
main.c getname 25
main.c getage  36
util.c namecheck 123
```

The above has first string file name, second function name, and third line no.
I want to:

1. Open the file(1st column)
2. Go to line no (3rd column)
3. Edit the string (2nd column).

Ex: Open the file main.c, change the string getname to getname() in line no 25

Does anyone know how to do the above using sed and awk?

I tried to use the following. But it doesn't work

```
awk '{ sed -e "$3s/$2/&()" <$1 >$1_new }' list
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the original files, you have to iterate over the filenames in `list` and copy them away, since otherwise redirection `>` would overwrite any previous change to the new file (which happens if you have several entries for the same file in `list`). Something along the lines of this would leave your originals untouched:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=testlist.txt

# get the first column in $list, sort it, remove duplicates
# and copy file to *_new. ignore if it doesn't exist
awk '{ print $1 }' "${list}" | sort -u | while read file; do
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue
    cp "${file}" "${file}_new"
done

# for each line in $list, get the filename, function name and line number
while read file func lineno; do
    # change filename to the one we wish to apply the changes to
    file="${file}_new"

    # file should exist as we just created it,
    # but if it doesn't, skip entry.
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue

    # replace
    sed -i "${lineno}s/${func}/${func}()/" "${file}"
done < "${list}"
```